# finding the next image

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html looks like -

```
<div id="slide1">
    <a href="#content1">
        <img src="demo_files/images/Carousel_Slides19-26/Slide19A.jpg" alt="" class="active1"/>
    </a>
    <a href="#content1">
        <img src="demo_files/images/Carousel_Slides19-26/Slide19B.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
```

I'm able to find the first image using jQuery with -

```
var $active = $('#slide1 .active1');
```

How do I use jQuery to find the next image without using that source within the selector? (The one with src="demo_files/images/Carousel_Slides19-26/Slide19B.jpg")

I thought

```
$('#slide1 .active1').next()
```

Would work, but the next element isn't that image.

Comment: are you looking for `$('#slide1 img')[1]`?

Comment: You may want `$('#slide1 img').eq(1)` but not indexing..

Answer (score 2):

Since `.active` is the `img` element, it does not have a next sibling so `.next()` won't work. You need to find the next sibling of the parent element(`a`) of `.active` like

```
$('#slide1 .active1').parent().next().find('img')
```

Comment: ... and to find next image (which is the question about) it should be something like `$('#slide1 .active1').parent().next().find('img')`

Answer (score 2):

select all image, and use `eq` to position the index.

```
var $active = $('#slide1 img').eq(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, You must make sure that only one ID in HTML.
`$('#slide1 .active1').next()` is equal to
`$('#slide1 .active1').eq(0).next()`

Following is resolutions:

1. `$('#slide1 img').eq(1)`
2. `$('#slide1 img')[1]`
3. `$('#slide1 .active1').parent().next().children().eq(0);`

Comment: How second option works? I tried it, but got an error.  Third option will not work, if there is something else before `img` in `a`. Fiddle about both options: http://jsfiddle.net/qxzcT/3/